# javascript how to create function service (constructor)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in AngularJs if you invoke service method:

```
app.service('nameService', function(){
this.Service = function (){console.log('hello')}
}
```

then you can use this service (object) :
nameService.Service()
so my question is how i can write function that have two arguments(name, function)

```
function service ( name, function ){
// how angular declare object with that value of first argument ? 
}
```

i'm ask how to write function like service(name,fn){} ?

Comment: You need to inject the service in a controller to use it. Is this what you mean or something else

Comment: no i not talk about angularJs  , i try to use js and function cunstractor to build function like service in angular. when you invoke service function in angular js , what the basic what happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs use [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to inject service.

"service" method is available on angular object because is on his Prototype.

```
angular.prototype.service = ...
```

you can read more about prototype inheritance, [MDN - Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 1):

you can use bracket notation , to get arguments value .

function service (name, fn){

```
    var createService = function(){
        return new fn()
    }

    this[arguments[0]] = func()
}

service('nameService',function(){
    //here you can use 'this' because it's function constructor

    this.getLog = function (){
        console.log('hello')
    }

})


//and you can user it like you  want nameService.getLog() 
//Console: hello
```